# Procedimiento almacenado para remplazar puntos(.) por comas(,) en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Me pueden ayudar porfavor, quiero hacer un procedimiento almacenado en MYSQL donde directamente, remplace los puntos (.) por comas (,).
ejemplo: entra un dato como (4.5) quiero que el procedimiento almacenado pase de ese dato a (4,5)

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado o investigado?, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: lo que intente fue como validacion por medio de HTML, pero cuando importo un excel con datos ya, la idea es que automaticamente el procedimiento tranforme estos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sería

Replace(NombreCampo, texto para cambiar, nuevo texto)

en tu caso sería

Replace(TuCampo,".",",")

Te invito a que busques más información en internet sobre la función replace de mysql

Comment: Ah vale entiendo, muchas gracias realmente si vi eso de remplace pero como se veia diferente a los procedimientos almacenados que yo veia, pense que solo servia para remplazar una vez y ya. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberías hacer es usar replace y mandar que datos deseas remplazar por ejemplo.

```
REPLACE("4.5", ".", ",")
```

Esto devolverá lo que deseas.

[Uso de Replace](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php)

Comment: Mmm pero en este caso quiero que eso suceda siempre, o sea automaticamente cada vez que se inserta un dato de este tipo.